# Back button support with Wordpress AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have been reading and researching how to support the back button on my site while using jquery ajax in wordpress. I have read about implementing hashes but there is still something I am not quite understanding. I am not really sure how implement it into my current code base.

**ajax.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {

  $(".product-cat").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxproducts.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'ajax_product_load',
            datavar: $(this).data( 'id' )
        },

        success: function ( result ) {
                $("#main").empty();
                $("#main").html( result );
            }
        })
  })
});
```

**plugin-functions.php**

```
<a href="#product-cat-name" data-id="5">Product Category Name</a>
```

When a user clicks the link, all data is retrieved through ajax just fine and loads all the products for that selected category. However, if the back button is pressed, it does not go back to the product category's page rather it goes back to the home page. I want it to be able to go back to categories page and if a user wants to bookmark the product page that they selected they should be able to.

Any help trying to figure this out would be appreciated.

Comment: you just can't use ajax with the back button from your browser

Comment: I have seen some cases where people have used ajax with the browser's back button, either with the HTML5 History API or using Javascript